# How can $n\log n +n $ is less than less than $n\log n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

How can we show, methodically, that $n\log n + n \ll n\log n$ ?

![Image][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNvy1.jpg “problem image”

Comment: What do you mean?  Obviously $n\log n+ n$ is greater than $n\log n$, at least for positive $n$ (and negative $n$ doesn't make sense here).

Comment: Should be and that’s why I’m confused ! This is problem 3.4.1 off of Jeffrey’s A Primer on Analytic Number Theory book.

Comment: Can you show the image?

Comment: What is the precise definition of "$\ll$" here?

Comment: [From section 3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoLrl.png)

Comment: Yes was just sharing the definition from section 3.1. thanks @NieDzejkob

Comment: @NieDzejkob Most stupid symbol ever. As it already means "much smaller that"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the notation, "$\ll$" is **not** asymmetric: we can have two functions $f,g$ such that $f\ll g$ **and** $g\ll f$ at the same time.

That's exactly what's happening here:

- $n\log n\ll n\log n+n$ trivially (take $C=1$).
- $n\log n+n\ll n\log n$ as well, however: taking $C=2$ we have for large enough $n$ that $$n\log n + n\le n\log n+n\log n=2n\log n=Cn\log n.$$

Note that the example right after the definition of $\ll$ also has this behavior: the text explains why $$7x^3-12x+9\ll x^3,$$ even though we obviously have $x^3<7x^3-12x+9$ for large enough $x$ (in this case consider $C=7$).

Comment: Absolutely! I did fail to see this! Thanks @Noah

Answer (score 1):

IMO the use of the relational operator $\ll$ is awkward, as it usually means "much smaller than". The common notation would be

$$n\log n+n=O(n\log n).$$

This is true because

$$n\log n+n\le 2n\log n$$
or
$$1\le \log n$$

for $n\ge e$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the definition of $\ll$ for $C = 2$, as eventually $n \log n + n \leq 2(n \log n)$.